# javascript similar Date objects, return defferent epochs?

Tags: javascript

when i use different Date constructors i receive similar Date objects but when i get there epoch values they have slightly different values.
Is it a bug or something or i'm just passing wrong value formats into constructors?

```
> date1 = new Date();
Sun Oct 04 2015 15:31:33 GMT+0330 (IRST)
> date2 = new Date(date1.toString());
Sun Oct 04 2015 15:31:33 GMT+0330 (IRST)
> date3 = new Date(date1.toISOString());
Sun Oct 04 2015 15:31:33 GMT+0330 (IRST)
> date1.getTime();
1443960093117
> date2.getTime();
1443960093000
> date3.getTime();
1443960093117
```

I'm using node(v0.12.2) in Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO date format includes a field to represent a fractional part of a second. The default date format doesn't, and when a default date format is parsed the system assumes the second value is exact.

```
> new Date().toString()
'Sun Oct 04 2015 07:53:48 GMT-0500 (CDT)'
> new Date().toISOString()
'2015-10-04T12:53:58.769Z'
```

In the ISO string, `.769` is the seconds fraction part.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `date1.toString()` does not take the milliseconds into account while `date1.toISOString()` does. Yes, this is not a bug, you're just passing different strings. For me:

```
var date1 = new Date();
console.log(date1.toString(), date1.toISOString())
// Sun Oct 04 2015 14:54:37 GMT+0200
// 2015-10-04T12:54:37.113Z
```

Answer (score 1):

When you just log a date it automatically uses the default method .toString() version which drops the milliseconds. Using the below code you can see that the .###Z is dropped for .toString() but not for .toISOString() because it is in the extended ISO format.

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(date1.toString());
var date3 = new Date(date1.toISOString());

console.log('date1 ' + date1.toISOString());
console.log('date2 ' + date2.toISOString());
console.log('date3 ' + date3.toISOString());
console.log('date1 ' + date1.getTime());
console.log('date2 ' + date2.getTime());
console.log('date3 ' + date3.getTime());
```

Which returns

```
date1 2015-10-04T13:34:37.778Z
date2 2015-10-04T13:34:37.000Z
date3 2015-10-04T13:34:37.778Z
date1 1443965677778
date2 1443965677000
date3 1443965677778
```

Hopefully this helps.